# Python formating all values in list of lists

Tags: python, list, format

I am so sorry that I asking so silly question
but could you help me please format list of lists ("%.2f") for example:

```
a=[[1.343465432, 7.423334343], [6.967997797, 4.5522577]]
```

I used:

```
  for x in a:
     a = ["%.2f" % i for i in x]
     print (a)
```

OUT:

```
['1.34', '7.42']
['6.97', '4.55']
```

But I would like to get my list of lists
OUT:

```
[['1.34', '7.42'] ,['6.97', '4.55']]
```

Comment: So just append `a` to a new list rather that `print()` it? Seeing that you already know how to use a list comprehension, just nest: `output = [['%.2f' % i for i in x] for x in a]`.

Comment: actually `a` is a bad choice of variable name in this case since you are looping through its elements to begin with. How about `b` like: `b += ["%.2f" % i for i in x]`?

Comment: @ Martijn Pieters Thank you. I used list list comprehension,but i did mistake in syntax

Comment: @ Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a simpler way, you may achieve the same using list comprehension as:

```
>>> a=[[1.343465432, 7.423334343], [6.967997797, 4.5522577]]
>>> [["%.2f" % i for i in l] for l in a]
[['1.34', '7.42'], ['6.97', '4.55']]
```

Infact even your code is fine. Instead of print, you need to just `append` the values you are printing to a list

Comment: Clever use of listcomp!

Comment: @ Moinuddin Quadri Will this script work in any length of list? I mean If I have 1000 list in one list with different  length

Comment: @ProtossReed: Yes, as far as it is list of lists (which I believe will always be true based on the question). Length of items will not matter.

Comment: @Moinuddin Quadri Thank you very much. I think VPfB answer is also looks well.

Answer (score 1):

A more general solution requires just a few lines. It recursively formats numbers, lists, lists of lists of any nesting depth.

```
def fmt(data):
    if isinstance(data, list):
        return [fmt(x) for x in data]
    try:
        return "%.2f" % data
    except TypeError:
        return data


a=[[1.343465432, 7.423334343], [6.967997797, 4.5522577], [10, [20, 30]], 40] 
print(fmt(a))
# [['1.34', '7.42'], ['6.97', '4.55'], ['10.00', ['20.00', '30.00']], '40.00']
```